# Making two IF statements in a manual input cell which reference two different cells

Tags: if-statement, nested, excel-2010, overwrite

Currently, I have Data Validation for cell E4, stating formula =IF(E4>1,””,1).  This prohibits the user from entering any number other than 1 or zero.

I need the user to manually enter the number “1” in cell E4 if a particular action is accomplished (a numerical checkbox, essentially).

I also want the value of cell E4 to read “1” if cell B4 reads the number “3”.

I’ve read several examples of nested IF statements and can’t find any that reference two different cells to decide the value of another cell.

Can I make nested IF statements in Data Validation?  I haven’t been successful in doing so.

The two formulas I need to affect cell E4 are;

IF(E4>1,””,1)
and
IF(B4=3,E4=1,””)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an OR statement.

=IF(OR(E4 > 1, B4 = 3),””,1)

Comment: Will that formula work in data validation?  I have to be able to enter a number in E4 without overwriting.

Comment: I'm not sure. Haven't done much with data validation in excel. It works in styling formulas, so it should. It should do after taking a quick look, all the validation rule will properly be something like "=OR(E4 > 1, B4 = 3)" as you want it to return true or false